# increment isn't working in Codeigniter via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here is my code

View ----

its a portion of whole segment-

```
<?php

                foreach ($popular_projects as $row) {
                    ?>

                    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                        <p><h5><a class="popular_project_a" id="<?php echo $row->project_thesis_id; ?>"
                                  href=""><?php echo $row->title; ?></a>
                        </h5></p>
                    </dl>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
```

JavaScript--------

container is the class of whole container div and click is working but the ajax is showing error with the id(project_thesis_id)

```
$('.container').on('click', ".popular_project_a", function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var project_thesis_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(project_thesis_id );
    change_popularity(project_thesis_id);


    var path = window.location.origin;

    if(path=='http://localhost'){

        window.location.replace(path+'/iit/about_iit/view_project/'+project_thesis_id);
    }else{
        window.location.replace(path+'/about_iit/view_project/'+project_thesis_id);
    }
});

function change_popularity(project_thesis_id){
    alert(project_thesis_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "about_iit/change_popularity/"+project_thesis_id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (success) {

            alert(success[0].total_view);

        },
        error:function(){
            alert('error');
            alert(project_thesis_id);
        }


    });
}
```

Controller---------

```
public function change_popularity($project_thesis_id)
        {
            $this->about_iit_model->update_popularity($project_thesis_id);

            echo(json_encode($this->about_iit_model->get_specific_project($project_thesis_id)));

        }
```

Model------

```
function update_popularity($project_thesis_id){
    $this->db->where('project_thesis_id', $project_thesis_id);
    $this->db->set('total_view', 'total_view+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->update('project_thesis');

}
```

javascript easily alerting the id(project_thesis_id).But the ajax isn't updating the table.The name and attribute of the table is correct as written. Why it isn't working? any Idea? Please...

Comment: What response are you getting?

Comment: error alert on ajax error function and database table isn't updating

Comment: Check in the browser dev tools for the error

Comment: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

that is a warning.not an error...what should i do?

Comment: No..What response you are getting from AJAX request?

Comment: sorry ... i don't understand what do u mean by  "AJAX request".. i am new in ajax..